# How do I fix org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

When I run the test method, I got the following output:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

For example:

```
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

Also, this error might show up because:

1. You stub either of: `final/private/equals()/hashCode()` methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. Inside `when()` you don't call a method on mock but on some other object.

```java
@Test
//  @Ignore("Fails when run with build")
public void FailWhenImNotReady() throws ApplicationException, SystemException {

    Map<String, String> rabbitMqProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    rabbitMqProperties.put("amqp.addresses", "10.20");
    rabbitMqProperties.put("amqp.virtualhost", "/pc");
    rabbitMqProperties.put("amqp.username", "Deejay");
    rabbitMqProperties.put("amqp.password", "deephouse");
    rabbitMqProperties.put("amqp.port", "9805");
    System.getProperties().putAll(rabbitMqProperties);

    UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
    userCredentials.setUserID("989864");
    userCredentials.setAuthenticationSystem("djp");

    EnterpriseMessageHeader enterpriseMessageHeader = new EnterpriseMessageHeader();
    enterpriseMessageHeader.setUserCredentials(userCredentials);

    LaunchAppRequest launchAppRequest = new LaunchAppRequest();
    launchAppRequest.setUcn("4848");
    launchAppRequest.setHeader(enterpriseMessageHeader);

    when(userLogon.isUserLoggedIn(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    when(Voice.lead()).thenReturn(76584l);
    when(ConnectionFactoryProvider.getVocalist()).thenReturn(mock(Vocalist.class));

    LaunchAppResponse response = AppLogicBean.launchApp(launchAppRequest);

    assertFalse(response.isSuccessful());
    assertEquals(response.getErrorMessage(), MusicProducer.PROXY_MSG);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors actually:

```java
    when(Voice.lead()).thenReturn(76584l);
    when(ConnectionFactoryProvider.getVocalist()).thenReturn(mock(Vocalist.class));
```

You are trying to mock static methods. Mockito cannot be used to mock static methods. If you really want to do that, you should look closer at [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito).